# How can i access a server side control from asp.net code behind file using reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

For example, if i have on the aspx page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="tab_0" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="tab_1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and i want to access these properties in the code behind page using values from a configuration file for example

```
string enabledTabs = "0,1,2,3";
```

if there a way i can use reflection to set them to enabled or disabled e.g.

```
foreach(var id in enabledTabs.Split(',')) 
{
  // <use reflection to get the correct tab control>

  // Set property of the tab
  tab.Visible = true;
}
```

I could acheive the result i want by using a switch statement and setting the particular control property, but i'd like to use reflection to get the tab to make it cleaner.

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need reflection. Use [Page.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx):

```
foreach(var id in enabledTabs.Split(','))
{
    PlaceHolder control = (PlaceHolder)this.FindControl("tab_"+id));
    control.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: +1 Just pass in the prefix `tab_` and append the number to form the ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var id in enabledTabs.Split(',')) 
{      

    // Set property of the tab
    Page.FindControl("tab_" + id.ToString()).Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Control tab = Control.FindControl("tab_"+id);
```